# How to fix "error: bad operand types for binary operator '||' " in java

Tags: java

I want to end the loop after the correct input.

It's working with the code inside the comment but is not working when I use 
|| operator. Is the first while equivalent with the second?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 

{
    char group, response;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    do
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("[1] Time for group A");
        System.out.println("[2] Time for group B");
        System.out.println("[3] Time for group C");
        System.out.println("[4] Quit program");

System.out.print("Enter choice[1,2,3,4]: ");

        response=sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println();
        switch(response)
        {
        case '1': System.out.println("10.00 a.m ");break; 
        case '2': System.out.println("1.00 a.m ");break;
        case '3': System.out.println("11.00 a.m ");break;
        case '4': System.out.println("Goodbye! ");break;
        default: System.out.println("Options 1-4 only!");
        }


    }   //while(response!='4'&&response!='3'&&response!='2'&&response!='1');
          while(response=='4'||response=='3'||response=='2'||response=='1');
```

I will expect to end the loop after the correct input in both cases.

Comment: What's the exact error? I'm not seeing anything obvious. It looks fine. (And I'm assuming the last bit in the comment should be `&&response!='1'`)

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Copy/pasted code and it compiles fine on my machine.

Comment: What is `not working`?

Comment: *"Is the first while equivalent with the second?"* Absolutely not. First, the commented condition is wrong, since it should probably be `!='1'` at the end. ANd why would you think that `!='4'` and `=='4'` could ever be equivalent?

Comment: This loop won't exit if you enter options 1-4, remove `response==4` from the condition if that's your goal.

Comment: *FYI:* Your loop condition should be just `while (response != '4')`, i.e. to end the loop when `response == '4'`

Comment: The commented-out code has redundant clauses because if the response is `'1'` of course it won't equal the others. Even if you flip the comparison to that value the expressions are not logically equivalent. One would be the negation of the other. `not A and not B` is equivalent to `not (A or B)`. Search "truth table" and "rules of formal logic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about the while loop condition directly (are the two conditions equivalent?):

No, they aren't equivalent, but it's only a small change needed. The following two conditions are equivalent by [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

```
boolean b1 =  (response != '4' && response != '3' && response != '2' && response != '1');
//                               (note: I corrected what looked like a typo here ^^)
boolean b2 = !(response == '4' || response == '3' || response == '2' || response == '1');
```

So basically you have to add a `!` before your second while loop condition to make them equivalent (assuming it really was a typo in the first one).

(Note: you still need to have the `!` inside the while loop parentheses though, so it will look like `while (!(...))`)

Comment: Best answer ... Thanks man! :D I know the code was wrong there, but I didn't notice before posting it.

Comment: No worries! If you are happy with this answer, could you please accept it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Well java operator precedence hit you. Use braces:

```
while((response=='4')||(response=='3')||(response=='2')||(response=='1'))
```

Explanation:

Literals of type char( like '1') are integer numbers. 
Now java evaluates your code for some weired reaseon like "( ... || response) == ..."  and complains because "response" is a char and not a boolean. If you use braces you ensure the monoms are evaluated first and the "||" gets booleans as operands. My opninion is: in cases like the above you shouldn't get the error -  but well, just uses braces and the error should go away.

Also the expresions are not equivalent. You get the equivalent by negeting each monom and the whole structure an toggle the operators.
The following is eqivalent to the above or:

```
while(!((response!='4')&&(response!='3')||(response!='2')&&(response!='1')))
```